# Django defaultdict dropping a value - cannot replicate

Tags: python, django, defaultdict

I'm converting a list of three tuples to a dictionary with the following format like so:

```
data = [(1, 4.0, 135.0),
       (1, 5.0, 336.0),
       (1, 6.0, 615.0),
       (2, 4.0, 50.0),
       (2, 5.0, 78.0),
       (3, 3.0, 110.0),
       (3, 4.0, 155.0),
       (3, 5.0, 188.0),
       (3, 6.0, 250.0)]

data_transform = defaultdict(list)

for item_ in data:
    data_transform[item_[0]].append(list(item_[1:]))

finished_data = dict(data_transform)
finished_data
```

And this returns what I'm seeking:

```
 {1 : [[4.0, 135.0], [5.0, 336.0], [6.0, 615.0]],
  2 : [[4.0, 50.0], [5.0, 78.0]],
  3 : [[3.0, 110.0], [4.0, 155.0], [5.0, 188.0], [6.0, 250.0]]}
```

This works as it should in ipython notebook and idol, however Django drops the first value, so that I have:

```
    { 2 : [[4.0, 50.0], [5.0, 78.0]],
      3 : [[3.0, 110.0], [4.0, 155.0], [5.0, 188.0], [6.0, 250.0]]}
```

Everything else is correct - it just keeps dropping the first value and as such it's causing problems later in my code. I've seen a couple stackoverflow posts regarding issues with default dict and django, but they were all related to templating, where as my code is in a view. I've run the same exact code in the django / python shell environment (python manage.py shell) and same issue.

Comment: Are you completely sure that the value of `data` is  exactly the same in both cases?

Comment: Is this `data` defined in the view exactly like you have done here or are you getting this data from somewhere else and how are you exactly getting it?

Comment: It's a django orm model - I have inspected the element in the shell environment and it definitely includes the value that is being dropped off (it's the very first value). I've also tried a raw query of the data - same issue, it's there in the data object, and then lost once it's transformed to the dictionary. Unbelievable!